# ARTool anova: Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list

Tags: r, anova

So I am trying to run the section of code

```
library(ARTool)
attach(salix.dat)
removal.art <- art(logSumSalix ~ as.factor(NewCode) + (1|Reach))
anova(removal.art)
```

and I keep getting the error message

> Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list

From what I have read in previous post you need to convert the data you are using into a data frame but I tried that and it produced the exact same error message. Does anyone know a work around for this problem?

Comment: It is not reproducible.  Please don't `attach` your data.  I don't get any error with the data in the documentation `m <- art(DryMatter ~ Moisture*Fertilizer + (1|Tray), data=Higgins1990Table5)`.  Please consider providing a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(salix.dat, 20)))`

Comment: Perhaps a typo? `removal.art <- art(logSumSalix ~ as.factor(NewCode) + (1|Reach))` doesn't appear to specify which dataset you are using - are you missing the `data = xx` argument? E.g. `removal.art <- art(logSumSalix ~ as.factor(NewCode) + (1|Reach), data = salix.data)`?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share this particular data set as it used by some researchers that I used to work with.

Comment: So you were right that problem was that I did not input data = salix.dat. Apparently the attach function does not work with art. Thank you so much.